# Which synchronisation method to use for data structure that maybe shared by *multiple processes*, [ another semaphore vs mutex question]?

Tags: linux, pthreads, mutex, semaphore, binary-semaphore

I am currently in the process of developing a **user-level device driver** for Linux, and I have a data structure that requires concurrent access from **multiple processes** (assume non related). I'm facing a dilemma regarding the choice of synchronization methods to prevent simultaneous access to the shared resource. I feel that mutex is the correct choice, but ChatGPT suggested that using *pthread_mutex* is not suitable for my case, and further said that its applicable only for threads of same process, but I can opt for a named semaphore for synchronizing between two process. However, I have reservations about the safety of utilizing a named semaphore, because the concept of ownership is not there for semaphore. So may you please help here?

I tried reading multiple answers regarding when to use semaphore and mutex from below links [Difference between binary semaphore and mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex) [When should we use mutex and when should we use semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039899/when-should-we-use-mutex-and-when-should-we-use-semaphore)
but the answers in this question didn't address the above question.

Comment: As you describe it, ChatGPT's response is more wrong than right.  Before I make any suggestion, however, would you please elaborate on your reservations about using a named semaphore?  What does ownership (of the semaphore, I presume) have to do with it?  More generally, can you say more about your synchronization requirements?

Comment: In particular, whatever synchronization object you use, for it to be effective, all the processes contending for access to the same resource must go through the same one. That one has to be owned by *somebody*.  I'm not appreciating what kind of ownership issue distinguishes semaphores (named or not) from pthreads mutexes for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBollinger for your reply,  from the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4043680/8140582,  what I understood is using  semaphore may lead to certain problems like accident release, priority inversion ,deadlocks of different types (I don't  deny the fact that deadlocks can occur in mutex as well), so in that answer, mutex  is posed as more safe compared to semaphore and I am a writing  a user level device driver GPIO framework , where multiple GPIO drivers can register, so there will be a list to maintain the drivers that are registered,

Comment: The answer you reference (and the articles *it* references) are directed to high-level mutex and semaphore concepts.  I don't see anything in them to object to, but you need to consider which, if any, of the issues they raise in favor of mutexes over semaphores are actually relevant to your project.  You also need to consider the practical details of the specific semaphore and mutex implementations available to you -- *these* are what you're deciding between, not semaphores and mutexes in the abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> regarding the choice of synchronization methods to prevent simultaneous access to the shared resource. I feel that mutex is the correct choice, but ChatGPT suggested that using pthread_mutex is not suitable for my case, and further said that its applicable only for threads of same process, but I can opt for a named semaphore for synchronizing between two process.

ChatGPT is not a reliable source for correct answers to technical questions, but in this case it happens to have lucked onto a bit of a point.

ChatGPT is wrong about pthreads mutexes only being applicable for synchronization inside a single process.  Pthreads mutexes *default* to being process-specific, but you can set them up for inter-process synchronization.  To make that work, you need to

- store the mutex in shared memory
- initialize it, once, supplying a `pthread_condattr_t` object having its `pshared` attribute enabled

However, having to access the mutex object in shared memory does present a bit of an issue for synchronizing **unrelated** processes.  You could do it with a SysV shared memory segment (and this is a *bona fide* option) or maybe with a memory-mapped physical file, but it would be pretty difficult with POSIX shared memory.  In this sense, a pthreads mutex is more analogous to an *unnamed* POSIX semaphore than to a named one.

For synchronizing unrelated processes, a semaphore really is the easier option.  Either a POSIX named semaphore or a SysV semaphore set would serve. The former has a simpler interface, but the latter has the distinctive feature that a process can be made to back out its semaphore adjustments automatically when it terminates, which is good for cleaning up from abnormal termination.

> I have reservations about the safety of utilizing a named semaphore, because the concept of ownership is not there for semaphore.

A semaphore is a more general synchronization construct than a mutex is.  Any task you can accomplish via a mutex, you can also accomplish via a semaphore.

As for ownership in particular, you seem to be talking about the fact that the thread or process that locks a mutex is the the only one that may unlock it.  So what?  If that's what you require then it is a *programming* error for your program to try to do it any other way.  Don't make that error.  The mutex helps you out a bit in that area because an erroneous unlock attempt will fail, whereas with a counting semaphore it will succeed.  That's not insignificant, but it's a matter of failure mode, not central to how well a semaphore, ***used correctly***, could serve your needs.

BOTTOM LINE: you are overthinking this.  Choose an option that is easy to work with for your purposes.  Factor the details into their own module, so that if you want to change later then you can do so without much trouble.  Either a mutex or a semaphore can serve your purpose, and each choice has both advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thank you very much John, what is your view on using flock(2)?

Comment: @ShamanthaKrishna, `flock` implements *advisory* locking, does not work over NFS, and does not, to my knowledge, have any of the memory-ordering semantics that pthreads mutexes and POSIX and SysV semaphores have.  I don't know enough about your requirements to make a recommendation, but `flock` plays in a different arena than the others do.