# Lock access to resource by threads

Tags: android, multithreading, resources, thread-safety

I have an app in which records audio files.
User can specify length of recorded audio, number of samples and time between recordings.
For example:

```
length   = 3 sec
samples  = 2
interval = 5 sec
```

When app starts it creates a thread, waits 5 seconds and creates second thread.

First thread records 3 seconds sample to a specified directory.

After 2 seconds, next thread starts recording second sample.
It works and creates two files: sample1.3gp, sample2.3gp.

But when user specify:

```
length   = 3 sec
samples  = 2
interval = 1 sec
```

recording cannot be done because of 2nd thread try to access to media recorder when 1st thread still uses it.

I want to be able to set some lock for that resource. What I mean ?

When 1st thread starts 3 seconds recording, after 1 second 2nd thread tries to record too.

But it should wait next two seconds until 1st thread finishes its job.

What is the best way to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read up on threading and mutex in general. [Read this SO question first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771347/what-is-mutex-and-semaphore-in-java-what-is-the-main-difference) and maybe refine what you're asking.

This isn't really an Android specific problem but more about threading with Java in general.