# using Object as a mutex in java

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, wait, notify

Hello there good poeple, I need some help.

I'm writing a music player which streams music from the web. If I pres the play button before the music is done buffering I want it to wait.

I tried doing something like this:

```
Object mutex = new Object();

public void main() {
    startStreaming();
    mutex.notify();
}

private void onClickPlayButton() {
    mutex.wait();
}
```

The problem is that is the playButton is not pressed the `mutex.notify()` if throws a "`llegalMonitorStateException`". How do you normally solve problems like this?

**EDIT** To make clear. My question is: How do I make the button wait for the "startStreamning" method to finish?

Comment: this might help (see accepted answer)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291041/is-there-a-mutex-in-java

Comment: Do you really need a mutex for this? I doubt you want to block the UI thread while the download finishes. I would think you could accomplish "don't play yet" by just checking a flag for `isDownloadComplete()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc,

> [IllegalMonitorStateException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) is thrown
>   "to indicate that a thread has
>   attempted to wait on an object's
>   monitor or to notify other threads
>   waiting on an object's monitor without
>   owning the specified monitor."

In order to call `mutex.wait()` or `mutex.notify()`, the calling thread must own a lock on object mutex.

This exception is thrown if you call it without a preceding `synchronized (mutex) { }`

Check out the nice animation of `wait` and `notify` in this link : [How do wait and notify really work?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=98786)

Answer (score 5):

for wait(), notify() call, you need a synchronized code. try this:

```
synchronized (this) {
  try {
    this.wait();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
}


synchronized (this) {
   notify();
}
```

Comment: To be more like the OP's code, the synchronized statements and the calls to `wait()` and `notify()` should be on `mutex` instead of `this`.

Comment: well, you're right. i would like to notice that the methods must be called in a sync. code.

Answer (score 4):

Try use [Semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with 0 initial permit.
Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(0);

in main `mutex.release();`

in on click `mutex.acquire();`

Comment: +1 for pointing to the concurrent.* package instead of error-prone fiddling with low-level synchronization primitives

Comment: It doesn't have to be set to a 1 permit?

Answer (score 2):

from javadoc
**wait**
*This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor*
and for **notify** 
*This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor.*

this means htat you have to synchronize using the mutex when using notify and wait

Answer (score 0):

You have to `wait` before you `notify`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. I know why I get the exception, I don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize on the mutex to call notify and wait

Answer (score 0):

You can either look at using more complex lock objects, or simply munch the exception in a try/catch block.  The later is definitely "quick and dirty".

For a more advance locking objects, take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html