# Making a Thread to Sleep for 30 minutes

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I want to make my thread to wait for 30 minutes. Are there any problems of doing this?

Comment: Yes, there are tons of problems, because your thread will do nothing for 30 minutes. `Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 30);` , and wrap it in a try-catch

Comment: instead of sleeping a thread try using timer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is this just to play around with threads?

Comment: Right. What's the application here, a timer may indeed be what you need.

Comment: @Kon - Why would a sleeping thread create "tons of problems"?

Comment: One problem is that testing your program will get awfully boring.  Make sure you have plenty of reading material.  :)

Comment: @TedHopp In my opinion, it's a mark of a bad design. It may not cause problems in the execution of the code, but it's almost always better to use a Timer or something similar to achieve your end-goal.

Comment: can anyone suggest me to how to use a timer with an example program or any reference link

Comment: The second part of the question is unanswerable. What would count as a "problem"?

Comment: The first part of the question is surely a duplicate question.

Comment: @Kon - A `Timer` is nothing more than a utility built on top of a background thread. I fail to see why it's so much better than using a raw `Thread`. Just like a `Thread`, a `Timer` by default does not use a daemon thread, so (like a `Thread`) it can prevent the application from terminating until the last task is run. Just like `Thread.sleep()`, a `Timer` also does not offer real-time guarantees. The only clear benefit of a `Timer` over a `Thread` is in scheduling multiple tasks, but that doesn't seem to apply here. (But who knows what OP is actually trying to accomplish.)

Answer (score 45):

You can make your thread sleep for 30 minutes like this:

```
Thread.sleep(30 *   // minutes to sleep
             60 *   // seconds to a minute
             1000); // milliseconds to a second
```

Using [`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) is not inherently bad. Simply explained, it just tells the thread scheduler to preempt the thread. `Thread.sleep` is bad when it is incorrectly used.

- **Sleeping without releasing (shared) resources**: If your thread is sleeping with an open database connection from a shared connection pool, or a large number of referenced objects in memory, other threads cannot use these resources. These resources are wasted as long as the thread sleeps.
- **Used to prevent [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)**: Sometimes you may be able to practically solve a race condition by introducing a `sleep`. But this is not a guaranteed way. Use a mutex. See [Is there a Mutex in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291041/is-there-a-mutex-in-java)
- **As a guaranteed timer**: The sleep time of `Thread.sleep` is not guaranteed. It could return prematurely with an `InterruptedException`. Or it could oversleep.

  From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)):

  > ```
  > public static void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException
  > ```
  >
  > Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, ***subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers***.

---

You could also use, as [kozla13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482700/kozla13) has shown in their comment:

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(30);
```

Comment: better solution: TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(30);

Comment: In Java 19+ you can also use: `Thread.sleep(Duration.ofMinutes(30))`

Answer (score 10):

The answer of Krumia already perfectly shows how to sleep a running `Thread`. Sometimes, the requirement to sleep or pause a thread originates from the wish to perform an operation at a later date. If that's the case, you should better use a higher level concept like `Timer` or `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.schedule(operation, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Where `operation` is the `Runnable` you want to execute in 30 minutes.

Using a `ScheduledExecutorService`, you can also execute operations periodically:

```
// start in 10 minutes to run the operation every 30 minutes
executor.scheduleAtFixedDelay(operation, 10, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```