# Creating an interval in java

Tags: java, multithreading, infinite-loop, intervals

I need to run a function every 10 seconds in my java project.
I want it to be like an infinite loop yet without using while(true) or thread.sleep...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought about anything yourself yet? Maybe you should look at the `Timer` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more or less a duplicate of [Making a Thread to Sleep for 30 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879303/making-a-thread-to-sleep-for-30-minutes). That question mentions the `ScheduledExecutorService`, which I've used and been very happy with. It's a bit heavyweight, so Timer may be all that you need. The [Java Tutorial](http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html) has a decent example of how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) with the method:

```
Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Here, `task` is the task you want to execute (derived from `TimerTask`), `period` is time in milliseconds between the execution of two tasks and `delay` is the delay in milliseconds *before* each execution.