# Write a custom class Mutex in java?

Tags: java, synchronization, mutex

I am learning multithread about synchronization.

**Require:**
Write mutex class in JAVA which has 2 methods

```
Class Mutex {

    acquire();

    release();
}
```

Can anybody help me for this. Thank in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the following post .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291041/is-there-a-mutex-in-java

Answer (score 2):

here [Tanembaum](http://stst.elia.pub.ro/news/SO/Modern%20Operating%20System%20-%20Tanenbaum.pdf) at page 128 there is the mutex example from the inventor of semaphores. 
It's in C, but it's very simple and readable, it is not difficult to "translate" it in java

```
Object lock = new Object();
int queue = 0


    void acquire() throws InterruptedException{
    synchronized (lock){
        while (queue > 0) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        queue ++;
    }
}

void release(){
    synchronized (lock){
        queue --;
        lock.notify();
    }
}
```

this is a binary mutex; by changing the number in the while condition, you can choose the max number of concurrent accesses

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#memorymodel_synchronized

I used it everytime I needed it. If you used shared variable between different threads you have to synchronize the modification.