# How I can put a lock around InputStream and release when reading is done

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

I want to put a Lock around `java.io.InputStream` Object and lock this stream. And when I am done finished reading I want to release the lock. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771347/what-is-mutex-and-semaphore-in-java-what-is-the-main-difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
InputStream is =
synchronized(is) { // obtains lock
    // read is
} // release lock
```

Its usually a good idea to use one thread to read or write to a stream, otherwise you are likely to get some confusing and random bugs. ;)

If you want to use a Lock as well

```
InputStream is =
Lock lockForIs = 
lockForIs.lock();
try {
    // read is
} finally {
    lockForIs.unlock();
}
```

Comment: A stream doesn't have an associated lock, unless you associate it.  You can lock a Lock, but unless the rest of your code also locks the same lock it won't do anything.  Why do you want a `Lock`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just lock on the InputStream, as it wouldn't prevent write access from a relevant OutputStream; you have to check the lock any time you want to write from the OutputStream.