# Confusion b/w mutex and semaphore

Tags: mutex, semaphore

I have read about mutex and semaphore from INTERNET , but I am not clear the difference b/w these two.
Can anyone please clear the confusion ? Please try to give example for both using java clearly stating difference.
Also is mutex same as binary semaphore ?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039899/when-should-we-use-mutex-and-when-should-we-use-semaphore/4039911#4039911.

Comment: Duplicate. [What is mutex and semaphore in Java ? What is the main difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771347/what-is-mutex-and-semaphore-in-java-what-is-the-main-difference)