# Difference between Semaphore and Mutex with respect to Priority Inversion ( and also, perhaps, priority inheritance )

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Well this topic isn't as simple as it appears. As we know a `mutex` can be implemented by a Semaphore with initial count=1. 
 But going through a few articles, I also found that tremendous amount of efforts has gone into separating these two, and treating `mutex` as a separate concept different from a `semaphore`
Problem of [Priority Inversion](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/RTOS-Priority-Inversion), which has lead to a new concept of [priority inheritance](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/RTOS-Priority-Inversion), somewhat appear confusing to me.

Also some people speak of mutex with respect to `ownership` ( as it appears in [what-is-mutex-and-semaphore-in-java-what-is-the-main-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771347/what-is-mutex-and-semaphore-in-java-what-is-the-main-difference) ). Well `ownership` is bad term. In no way , Mutex is an owner of a shared resource. `Holding a Lock` and `Releasing a Lock`, are effectively a way of signalling, perhaps like,  `*Hey wait !! Till I complete and signal you*`

Looking for some concrete reasons that has lead to a separation of `Mutex` from a `Semaphore` ( with initial count = 1 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ownership means you cannot lock mutex in one thread and release in another. So semaphore is more universal. You can do dumb mutex realisation with just a semaphore but you can't do semaphore with JUST a mutex.

Priority inversion is a following situation:

1) high priority thread A waits for mutex

2) low priority thread B holds it but couldn't execute until it releases it cause

3) mid-priority thread C occupies CPU

To handle such situation scheduler should have some logic:

to start A sooner allow B to execute instead of C

To understand that it is B who stop A it have to know mutex owner.
For semaphores it is impossible to say who unlocks it: B or C. So no way to perform such kind of logic.

Comment: Yes your are right. For priority inheritance to work, thread B will temporarily inherit the priority of the higher-priority thread A. Essentially just a `conditional variable`, such as `semaphore` is not always enough. Though a `mutex` can be simulated with a semaphore but only for limited set of scenarios. For E.g: `recursive mutex` and `monitors` are more complicated to be implemented just by a `semaphore`. Also I found this link very useful : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_variable#Condition_variables

Answer (score 0):

Mutexes in Java (both in forms of intrinsic locks and java.util.concurrent.Lock) are nicely combined with event notification mechanism. Implementing such a full-blown mutex by Semaphores is problematic: it requires releasing one semaphore and acquiring another one as an atomic transaction.

Comment: Well, not sure of what you are saying.. I mean in terms of `event notification mechanism`. But anyways the questions is a general one, not related to a specific programming language. You see what I am saying, - are you attaching the meaning and differences of `mutex` and `semaphore` with respect to Object Oriented Programming ?